# HtmlUnit on Android: Dependencies

Tags: java, android, htmlunit, noclassdeffounderror

The code works in a normal Java project, but if I try it on Android, copying the library (.jar) dependencies, it will fail to build:

> warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (org.apache.commons.collections.BeanMap$1) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

It finally says:

> 6 warnings
>   1 error; aborting
>   /home/kp/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:818: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/kp/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:820: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/kp/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:832: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/kp/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:278: null returned: 1

I added all the libraries:

- commons-codec-1.4.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-io-2.0.1.jar
- commons-lang-2.6.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- cssparser-0.9.5.jar
- htmlunit-2.9.jar
- htmlunit-core-js-2.9.jar
- httpclient-4.1.2.jar
- httpcore-4.1.2.jar
- httpmime-4.1.2.jar
- nekohtml-1.9.15.jar
- sac-1.3.jar
- serializer-2.7.1.jar
- xalan-2.7.1.jar
- xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
- xml-apis-1.3.04.jar

If I remove some dependencies, it will build but when it tries to execute my code `_client = new WebClient();` I get noClassDefFoundError errors.

I haven't found a solution yet nowhere, so if you have the solution please share!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your HTMLunit jars are not placed in the libs folder of the Android project.

You should create a libs folder (use the exact spelling) under the root of your project and place all of the HTMLUnit jars under that folder.

i.e.

Project/libs/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the noClassDefFoundError errors by checking the boxes next to all the libraries I added in the "Order and Export" tab of the Eclipse build path dialog. I think this includes the .jars in the .apk so that you can use them on the device.

Comment: Oh, and I've safely ignored the "inner class" warnings.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is deleting the following:
xalan-2.7.1.jar
xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
xml-apis-1.3.04.jar